# Shape Context - Rotation Invariance

Tags: matlab, descriptor

I was trying to implement Shape Context (in MatLab).  I was trying to achieve rotation invariance.

The general approach for shape context is to compute distances and angles between each set of interest points in a given image.  You then bin into a histogram based on whether these calculated values fall into certain ranges. You do this for both a standard and a test image.  To match two different images, from this you use a chi-square function to estimate a "cost" between each possible pair of points in the two different histograms.  Finally, you use an optimization technique such as the hungarian algorithm to find optimal assignments of points and then sum up the total cost, which will be lower for good matches.

I've checked several websites and papers, and they say that to make the above approach rotation invariant, you need to calculate each angle between each pair of points using the tangent vector as the x-axis.  (ie http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~malik/papers/BMP-shape.pdf page 513)

What exactly does this mean?  No one seems to explain it clearly.  Also, from which of each pair of points would you get the tangent vector - would you average the two?

A couple other people suggested I could use gradients (which are easy to find in Matlab) and use this as a substitute for the tangent points, though it does not seem to compute reasonable cost scores with this.  Is it feasible to do this with gradients?

Answer (score 1):

Should gradient work for this dominant orientation?

What do you mean by ordering the bins with respect to that orientation?  I was originally going to have a square matrix of bins - with the radius between two given points determining the column in the matrix and the calculated angle between two given points determining the row.

Thank you for your insight.

Comment: please use the comment section for your questions

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving (somewhat) rotation invariance is to make sure that where ever you compute your image descriptor their orientation (that is ordering of the bins) would be (roughly) the same. In order to achieve that you pick the dominant orientation at the point where you extract each descriptor and order the bins with respect to that orientation. This way you can compare bin-to-bin of different descriptors knowing that their ordering is the same: with respect to their local dominant orientation.
From my personal experience (which is not too much) these methods looks better on paper than in practice.